# How do you copy a Azure storage container and it's contents to a new storage container programatically

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I have a desktop WinForms application using VB/C#.  I store images in Azure through this app.  I'm using the address of our clients/clients locations for the container name.  Sometimes these addresses change which make the container name/directories/blobs no longer valid.  Is there a way to programmatically copy 1 container and all it's contents to a new container or will I have to download each image and then upload it to a new azure container?

Comment: Please search for copy blobs and you will find plenty code samples to do that. You don't need to download each image and then upload it to a new azure container.

Answer (score 0):

The following link has the documentation for the REST API for the Storage Account https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts

This is Azure Storage REST API Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/

This is the Azure Storage Blobs client library for .NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.blobs-readme